# R Combining arrays from function

Tags: r, web-scraping

OK day 3 of R and I'm stuck, again.

I am trying to build a simple web scraper from the ground up (because I can and because it will help me learn how - rather than just copying someone else's code).

**How it works**
Given a set of variables the scraper;
- constructs a Google search URL
- makes the query and stores the results in an array
- then a scraper runs through the array and grabs the resulting webpage, saving it locally

Simple.

This all works for the first page of results but extending it to multiple pages has thrown a spanner in there.

I can construct an array of Google search URLs for each page upto a specified number of desired results.  BUT when I run the queries rather, each iteration is overwriting the results of the previous query - and I cannot fathom how to handle this.

```
# variables used
    googleURL_root <- "https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=site%3A"
    domainURL_root <- "coindesk.com"    # these could come from a file as an array to iterate through
    searchTerm <- "russia"
    searchMinDate <- "%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F4%2F2013"   # easier for now just to put date in google format
    searchMaxDate <- "%2Ccd_max%3A31%2F3%2F2014"   # easier for now just to put date in google format
    searchAttribs <- "&safe=off&biw=1280&bih=705&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1"    #all the other gubbins required in google search url
    searchPostAttribs <- "&tbm="    #all the other gubbins required in google search url
    resultXPath <- "//h3//a[@href]"
    resultURLStrip <- "(/url[?]q=)|(/&sa.*)" # pre and post result url regex (will change sometimes)
    maxResults <- 0:40 # how many results to return 0:40 = first to fortieth result
    pageSize <- 10 # default number of results returned per Google page

# include libraries
    require(XML)
    require(RCurl)
    require(plyr)

googleScrape <- function()
{
  # pageIterator
  startPages <- maxResults[seq(1, length(maxResults), pageSize)] # return array of start numbers in pages of pageSize (10 default)
  pageNum <- paste0("&start=",startPages) # create &start= attrib with result start number
  #search URL is concatenated 
  searchURIS <- str_c(googleURL_root,domainURL_root,"+",searchTerm,searchAttribs,searchMinDate,searchMaxDate,searchPostAttribs,pageNum, sep = "", collapse = NULL)

  #for each in searchURIS
  for (i in seq_along(searchURIS))
  {
    html <- getURL(searchURIS[i], .opts=list(useragent="Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; en-US; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13"))   # read in page contents
    parsed <- htmlParse(html)    # parse HTML into tree structure
    nodes <- xpathApply(parsed, resultXPath, xmlAttrs)   # extract url nodes using XPath. 
    results <- sapply(nodes, function(x) x[[1]])    # extract urls
    free(parsed)   # free doc from memory
    uris <- gsub(resultURLStrip, "", results) # strip out the leading and post Google gubbins from URLs
    #write.table(uris,file="uris.txt", append = true)
  }
}
```

Fairly hopeful the problem lays in the `for` loop.  If there is only a single page of search results then `uris` contains;

```
> uris
 [1] "http://www.coindesk.com/btc-e-concerns-russian-criminal-investigation"                 
 [2] "http://www.coindesk.com/russian-tech-magnates-first-bitcoin-project-launches-beta"     
 [3] "http://www.coindesk.com/ceo-russian-sberbank-endorses-virtual-currencies"              
 [4] "http://www.coindesk.com/russias-biggest-search-engine-launches-bitcoin-conversion-tool"
 [5] "http://www.coindesk.com/russian-prosecutors-office-btc-e-investigation-hoax"           
 [6] "http://www.coindesk.com/payments-become-political-weapons-mass-destruction"            
 [7] "http://www.coindesk.com/russian-bar-killfish-accepts-bitcoin"                          
 [8] "http://www.coindesk.com/bitcoin-conference-goes-ahead-moscow-despite-uncertainty"      
 [9] "http://www.coindesk.com/crisis-ukraine-displays-us-power-over-payment-systems"         
[10] "http://www.coindesk.com/estonian-central-bank-warns-bitcoin-ponzi-scheme"
```

A second page would just replace this with new URLs.  In an ideal world I would end up with something more like...

```
> uris
 [1] "http://www.coindesk.com/btc-e-concerns-russian-criminal-investigation"                 
 [2] "http://www.coindesk.com/russian-tech-magnates-first-bitcoin-project-launches-beta"     
 [3] "http://www.coindesk.com/ceo-russian-sberbank-endorses-virtual-currencies"              
 [4] "http://www.coindesk.com/russias-biggest-search-engine-launches-bitcoin-conversion-tool"
 [5] "http://www.coindesk.com/russian-prosecutors-office-btc-e-investigation-hoax"           
 [6] "http://www.coindesk.com/payments-become-political-weapons-mass-destruction"            
 [7] "http://www.coindesk.com/russian-bar-killfish-accepts-bitcoin"                          
 [8] "http://www.coindesk.com/bitcoin-conference-goes-ahead-moscow-despite-uncertainty"      
 [9] "http://www.coindesk.com/crisis-ukraine-displays-us-power-over-payment-systems"         
[10] "http://www.coindesk.com/estonian-central-bank-warns-bitcoin-ponzi-scheme"  
[11] "http://www.coindesk.com/...
```

In other words a long list with each iteration of the `for` loop just appending to the previous.  I tried using `write.table` but that just throw an error.

As ever help gratefully received on this huge learning curve of a journey ;o)

Comment: If you're only just learning R, maybe start with some easier stuff...unless you have a due date and this must be done with R.

Answer (score 0):

Your code writes `uris` during each loop. You need to save each result to another dimension of an array or, I think preferably, use a list.

Before the `for` loop, assign `uris <- list()` to store the result, then assign the result of each loop to the ith element of `uris`.

You might also try replacing the `for` with a list apply, `lapply()`.

```
uris <- lapply(seq_along(searchURIS), function(i)
{
    html <- getURL(searchURIS[i], .opts=list(useragent="...")) 
    parsed <- htmlParse(html)    # parse HTML into tree structure
    nodes <- xpathApply(parsed, resultXPath, xmlAttrs)
    results <- sapply(nodes, function(x) x[[1]])
    free(parsed)
    gsub(resultURLStrip, "", results)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response which kind of makes sense (as I said this is only day three of learning R).  

Does this mean that the last part of the googleScrape function would end up looking like...  


`  uris <- list() `
  
`  lapply(seq_along(searchURIS), function(i)`
`  {`
`    html <- getURL(searchURIS[i]) `
`    parsed <- htmlParse(html)    # parse HTML into tree structure`
`    nodes <- xpathApply(parsed, resultXPath, xmlAttrs)`
`    results <- sapply(nodes, function(x) x[[1]])`
`    free(parsed)`
`    uris[i] <- gsub(resultURLStrip, "", results)`
`  }`

Comment: The output from lapply() has to be assigned to something, which I forgot. Also, I edited out the string assigned to useragent, for clarity.